# How to see all the views in mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, project, projects-and-solutions

I added a default MvcApplication (MVC 4) (its name is `MvcApplication3` matching the name of my solution's) width Home views (About, Index, Contact) and that will be my startup (bold in VS solution explorer's interface) project. Then I added another project (MvcApplication, but this time an empty one) called `MvcApplication2` to the solution. Then I added the latter project as a reference to the first. I also added a controller called `TestController` (**green line**) to the referenced project and generated a view for its `Index` (**red arrow**) method. However, when I go to a link `/Test` or `/Test/Index`, the view I am expecting (**red arrow**) is not shown. Then I added the same folder `Test` with `Index.cshtml` (**blue arrow**) to the main project and now I am seeing its contents rather than the project's where my controller sits in.

**Is it possible to make the application look for the views in the other project rather than the startup one?**

I am adding the image of the structure to make it easier to follow.

P.S.: probably related: the breakpoint **IS** being hit in the `Index` method of `TestController`.

### *tldr; blue view is used instead of a red one*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some ideas from me and a friend of mine and a [link](http://www.techiesweb.net/rendering-views-from-custom-folders-in-asp-net-mvc/) about overriding `RazorViewEngine` I finally got what I wanted working exactly how I was expecting it to:

1. I created a folder named `ViewsBase` in the main project.
2. I rewrote `RazorViewEngine` this way: I only changed the place that was needed for me, leaving everything else like I found in the constructor of `RazorViewEngine`:

   `public class MyCustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
   {
       public MyCustomViewEngine()
       {
           ...`

   ```
        ViewLocationFormats = new[]
        {
             "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
             "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
             "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
             "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
             "~/ViewsBase/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
             "~/ViewsBase/{1}/{0}.vbhtml"
        };

       ...
   ```

*(I find it rather disturbing how I am unable to format the code properly. Can someone give me a hand please?)*

and in `Global.asax` of the main project I added:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
var ourViewEngine = new 
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(ourViewEngine);

AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
...
```

1. I added a post-build event command:

   `xcopy /s "$(ProjectDir)Views\*.*" /Y "$(SolutionDir)$(SolutionName)\ViewsBase\"`
2. It started looking for the views in the expected order
3. I added a ViewStart file to the base project to make it render the Layout too.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problema is that you have set MvcApplication3 as startup Project and is causing you to open the view off that Project.

> Is it possible to make the application look for the views in the other
>   project rather than the startup one?

Yes its posible, you can redirect your application  the url. Think this your application have a url `http://localhost:(someport)` you can set redirect to the port of the second application.

I put a link to for better understanding a routing system of MVC: [Documentation of routing system](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have no intention to have two applications, I want two `projects`. And yes, it is opening like because that is how `routeConfig` is defined. However, I am pretty sure that this could be solved. Lastly, do you have anything specific for me to take a look at in your link, because I can only see it talking about rather simple examples in a single project application?

Comment: Sorry this is a general documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't link to projects together like that. Each project becomes its own website with its own address. The reason you might put multiple projects together in one solution is to share things like classes, services, etc. I think what you're needing is areas:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC